# how to pass two dimensional array to another function javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, codeigniter

i want to get header function main headers and sub headers into two dimensional array. and pass that array into another function.because i want to check that print value exact match that main header under the subheader.

i declare two dimensional array below the function.
like this,

```
   var code = [[]];
```

headers function main headers to i assign subcategory and sub headers are code.
so i call that two dimensional array like this,

```
   if (tmp === free['b'][y].subcategory) {
                html += '<td hidden="true">' + free['b'][y].code + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + free['b'][y].code + '</td>';
                -------------------------------------
                code= [ free['b'][y].code];
               --------------------------------------
              // alert(code [code]); [cryspy,mmnuts cryspy,mmjhf  cryspy,bbghr Bar,ffata Bar,yjkou.....etc]


            }
            else {

                html += '<td></td>';
                html += '<td hidden="true">' + free['b'][y].code + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + free['b'][y].code + '</td>';
                tmp = free['b'][y].subcategory;
```

then i call that array into another function for get values for that sub headers.

```
       for (var i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
               //
               //  alert(code.length); display: 324
              for (var k = 0; k < cat[i].length; k++) {
             //alert(cat[i].length);//display 2
                    for (var y = 0; y < order['rd'][x].qty.length; y++) {
   // alert("code1 ==  " + code[i] + " , code2 ==  " + order['rd'][x].qty[y].code); display code1==crspy,mmkhh code2===jklll
        //  console.log(code[i] === order['rd'][x].qty[y].code);
        // alert(order['rd'][x].qty.length);
                        if (code[i] === order['rd'][x].qty[y].code) {

                        //alert(order['rd'][x][y].code);
                            order_detail += '<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid black; border-right:1px solid black; padding: 3px; text-align:right">' + order['rd'][x].qty[y].qty + '</td>';
                            break;
                        } else {
                            order_detail += '<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid black; border-right:1px solid black; padding: 3px; text-align:right">0</td>';
                            break;
                        }
                       } 
                   }  
             }
```

but its not print qty.is the two dimentional array is wrong ...or?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: no i can not. because data call from model file

Comment: can you share the html?